# `print` stdin without file

Tags: batch-file, printing

Suppose in a CMD (Windows 7) batch file I want to print the contents of a directory. I'd expect to do something like this:

```
dir | print
```

But this doesn't work, because `print` apparently requires a file. Is there an intelligent one-liner to do this? (preferably not involving file manipulation)

Comment: @MarkSetchell I think that's an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following

```
dir > f && print f
```

If you get the error `Unable to initialize device PRN`, then you will need to specify the printer using the `/D:` switch with the print command. You can also delete the file after running the command if you want.

```
dir > f && print f /D:"Printer Name" && del f
```

To do it without outputting to a file you can just redirect the command output to a shared printer.

```
dir > \\share\printer
```

To get a list of shared printers use PowerShell

```
get-WmiObject -class Win32_printer | ft name, systemName, shareName
```

I prefer outputting to a file then printing the file, so the name of the print job has some relevance to the actual content.

Comment: I knew about that. I was asking about a way to do that without the file stuff.